# How to format PHP preg_match

Tags: php

How do I find these and other options:

```
<title itemprop="name">Title</title>
<title>Title</title>
```

with this

```
preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the titles then you'll probably want to use `preg_match_all` nd not `preg_match`. You should also take into consideration that there might be extra data (such as attributes) right after the `<title`. Lastly, your "greater-than" sign should be changed to a "greater-than" - you're looking until a new tag is begining.

Here's a working solution:

```
preg_match_all('/<title[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match );
```